# Shorthand not null C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Is it possible to do a conditional not null like this?

```
object e = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c) ?? d;
```

it it possible?

Comment: Well your brackets are mismatched to start with... and we have no idea of the type of d.

Comment: Come on guys, you get the gist, no need to be so harsh.

Comment: @Mike_G: No, I don't get the gist. Jon's comment is exactly what I was thinking when I read this code. Sure, we can figure out where the brackets are supposed to go. But how are we supposed to infer the type of `d`? That could be absolutely anything because the declaration isn't shown in the example code. We have high expectations for questions around here for a reason, namely it makes answering them possible.

Comment: @Cody Gray  The gist is easy: If this string is not null or empty, assign it to object e, if it is, assign whatever d is to e.  If e is an object, does it really matter what d is?  No, because her question is "is it possible".  And its not, ?? doesnt work that way, but we can sure offer suggestions that to point her in the right direction in accomplishing her goal.

Comment: Someone could have just fixed the brackets...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try the below.

```
object e = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(c) ? c : d;
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do

```
object e = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(c) ? d : c);
```

Comment: This will compile to the same MSIL as the following

    `object e; if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(c)) { e = d; } else { e = c; }`

Answer (score 1):

You could do an extension method:

```
public static object DontReplaceIfNullOrEmpty(this object c, object d)
    {
        if(c is string)
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty((string) c) ? c: d;

        return c ?? d;
    }



object e = c.DontReplaceIfNull(d);
```

Comment: Feels like taking out the Stinger just to kill a mosquito.

Comment: I didnt create the problem, only provided solution :-).  If its a piece of code used frequently, its defenitely easier than having to write the conditional statement all the time.

Comment: Must resist urge to downvote .... any programmer that doesn't understand the ternary operator doesn't deserve to call themselves C/C++/C# literate.

Comment: @Mike_G: I've just noticed that this would probably need a `where T : class` in order to compile.

Comment: Ya, just changed it to be more illustrative of what she is wanting

Comment: @Mike_G - You're not using it wrong. But replacing the ternary with a function call that wraps the ternary would be awful.